# Can you change a structure using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, linux, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to LD_PRELOAD a function with different parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871938/is-it-possible-to-ld-preload-a-function-with-different-parameters)

I have a structure, lets call it **my_struct**, which is declared as follows.

```
struct my_struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
}
```

For some reason I want to add a new field to it, so I want to change it as follows.

```
struct my_struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
}
```

Say I do this in my shared object library which I then LD_PRELOAD to run the program. Will my program use the second definition or the original one.

Comment: It's not quite the same question.

Comment: Well, you can achieve similar functionality in round about manner if you are in a position to modify the original library whose functions you want to over-ride. 

Otherwise its not possible.

Comment: What I mean is that if you write original code in certain way, future modifications via LD_PRELOAD are possible

Comment: It is not difficult to override certain types of functions with `LD_PRELOAD`. Modifying a structure is a completely separate matter. For this reason, all the close votes on this question are incorrect.

Answer (score 10):

No, the original code will not use the new definition. Imagine the case if it did and what would have to change. Firstly, each `my_struct` on the heap would have to be expanded to include the new field. This would likely mean that data sections have to be resized and all data that is shifted forward would need its references relocated. `sizeof struct my_struct`, which is evaluated at compile-time would then be inconsistent with the new definition. These are just a few of the reasons which make what you are trying to do impossible (at least in the way you're attempting).

The original code that was compiled and linked against the old definition will continue to use the old `my_struct`. Any **new code in your shared object** will be compiled against and use the new definition and hence will have a `c` field.

Once the original program has been compiled, it does not know anything about `my_struct`. That information is just used by the compiler to generate offsets to access structure members and allows it to know how to lay it out in memory. It is possible that information is still available in the form of symbols but this would not effect how the definition is picked up. Unlike function resolution, the code/data generation and resolution of a structure is strictly a compile-time operation.