# What is the easiest way to add a field to a structure in a shared library?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I want to add a new field to the `pthread_mutex_t` structure. Is it enough to change the `pthread.h` header file for this purpose? But I guess it's not a good idea because then I would be tampering with the header files that are shipped with the compiler.

What are the other ways to do so?

I'm doing this because I'm LD_PRELOADing `pthread_mutex_lock` and my custom `pthread_mutex_lock` requires one extra field inside `pthread_mutex_t`. Sure I can write code so that I use a structure other than `pthread_mutex_t`, but I don't want the user to modify its program.

Comment: You really should start elaborating/expanding on your existing questions rather than spammily reposting every time there's a new aspect to the question...

Comment: Hacking system headers like `pthread.h` is a recipe for disaster.  Don't do it.  (Like optimization, there's a second rule, for experts only: Don't do it yet.)

Comment: Xrefs to the prior works of the OP: [Is it possible to LD_PRELOAD a function with different parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871938/), [Will this trick work in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872130/), [Can you change a structure using LD_PRELOAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872449/).

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to expand the `pthread_mutex_t` structure without recompiling **everything** that could possibly depend on it. This means all your system libraries, third party libraries, and your application. There is simply no way around this.

Can you please explain what actual problem you're trying to solve by doing this? That might make it possible for somebody to give you an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot. But you could do something like the following:

```
struct my_pthread_mutex_t {
   pthread_mutex_t mutex;
   ...
   /* insert fields here */
   ...
};
```

This should allow you to have the same address for `pthread_mutex_t` and `my_pthread_mutex_t`. So if a function is aware about this `hack`(that is if the struct declaration is in scope) you can cast to my_pthread_mutex_t, otherwise you can use the same stuff as a simple pthread_mutex_t.

The plus, by expanding the structure like this, is that you don't have to recompile any code, and you don't risk to mess things up for the other programs that make a legitimate use of `pthread_mutex_t`

Comment: The problem is that OP wants to *replace* the standard function using `LD_PRELOAD`, and then OP's replacement function will get called with pointers to (standard size) `pthread_mutex_t` objects without sufficient space for the extra field, and the replacement code will then clobber adjacent memory.